# Firebase database. Ждать ответ сервера

Tags: android, асинхронность, firebase-database

Нужно подождать пока firebase вернет данные, а потом продолжить работу приложения. В приложении реализована функция предзагрузки, т.е. в `onCreate` запускается предзагрузка, далее загружаются данные из firebase, приложение ждет пока все загрузится из firebase и убирает предзагрузку, запуская остальные функции. Как это реализовать?

P.S. Предзагрузка уже реализована, нужно получить данные из firebase асинхронно.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Собственно не асинхронно данные вроде и нельзя получить... Т.е. иначе как нужным вам способом реализовать и нельзя. У вас проблема в том, что вы знаете как получать событие на каждого ребёнка к-л ноды, но не знаете как получить один вызов на всех детей ноды?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, данные я получаю, я не знаю как подождать пока я получаю все данные

Comment: Думаю вам надо `приложение ждет пока все загрузится и убирает предзагрузку` заменить на `приложение ждет пока все загрузится ИЗ FIREBASE и убирает предзагрузку`